# Jenkins limit views based on user

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have a few Jenkins jobs. I also have a few users.
I'd like to allow some users to only view certain Jenkins jobs.

For example, I might have the following users:

1. live
2. staging

and the following jobs:

1. a-live
2. b-live
3. a-staging
4. b-staging

I'd want the staging user to only view the *-staging jobs

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make matrix authorization strategy for each project as below.

1. **Manage Jenkins** > **Configure Global Security** > Choose **Project-based Matrix Authorization Strategy** at *Authorization* section.
2. Add global ACL at the matrix here. For example, check all for an admin user as below.
   [image]
3. For the project *a-live*, go to the configuration page of the project, check **Enable project-based security**
4. Add ACL for the user *live*. If you don't make any ACL for user *staging* here, he cannot see this job on his view (nor do anything against the job). 
   [image]
5. Configure auth matrix for the other projects similarly.